# Entity frame work .Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<object>'

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i am trying to save the object it did not allow me to do so.
giving me type conversion error.
i have populate an object and trying to pass it to DBset, and save it use savechanges.

```
 public class UserContext: DbContext
    {
        public UserContext()
        {

        }

      public virtual DbSet<Users> User { get; set; }
   // public virtual DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }

}
```

saving using this method

```
   public bool registerUser(Users user)
    {
        userContext = new UserContext();
        userContext.User = user;
        userContext.SaveChanges();
        return false;
    }
```

Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet'

Need help!

Comment: em... it's not enough. Add calling code and so on

Comment: public bool registerUser(Users user)
        {
            userContext.User = user;
            userContext.SaveChanges();
            return false;
        }

Comment: edit your question and add this code

Comment: Include your `userContext` code.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you need to call `Add` method:

```
    public bool registerUser(Users user)
    {
        userContext = new UserContext();
        userContext.User.Add(user);
        userContext.SaveChanges();
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Now this error is showing...A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist.

Comment: @BilalQadeer this is another error, you should ask new question or find answer (because, it's very popular error)